# Issues in align image in colums in css

Tags: html, css

Here is my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/3om4yjpa/

The three images of columns at the bottom it didn't align properly.

I need something like this http://s11.postimg.org/pzq7m2glv/Untitled_1_copy.png

html:

```
  <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;" align="left" valign="top">            
  <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/e6686072-3933-4150-b034-eef1599bc277.jpg" style="max-width:186px;" class="mcnImage" width="164">          
</td>
```

And i have to edit only inline css, can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure: you can't chance the HTML of the page? Because using `<table>` for this is not the best way to go. If you can chance the HTML as well, I can give you an improved version.

Comment: Actually it is code from mailchimp.. so it is not possible to change table . thanks

Comment: set height for table.mcnCaptionBlock to approx 350px;

Comment: Try to add `code snippet` here instead of providing link to jsfiddle. It will help to simulate code on stack overflow itself.

Comment: anyone is there thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can give height to table if it is fixed because `min-height` is not possible for table.

```
.mcnCaptionBlock 
 {
    height: 350px;
 }
```

and remove `margin-left:10px` of span.

```
span{
margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Check updated [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3om4yjpa/3/)

Comment: Try to add `code snippet` here instead of providing link to jsfiddle. It will help to simulate code on stack overflow itself.

Comment: @rish `<span style="color:#fff;margin-left: 11px;font-size: 16px;font-family: arial;">RV Roof Repair Boxes</span>` it will take `margin-left: 11px;`

Comment: I need to use only inline css.. then how is it possible .mcnCaptionBlock 
 {
    height: 350px;
 } ? thanks

Comment: you can give `height:350px;` to your table in inline css. like: `style="height:350px;"`

Comment: @ketan: in your jsfiddle, the gap between those images still remains same. right? but i need like this http://s11.postimg.org/pzq7m2glv/Untitled_1_copy.png .thanks

Comment: @rish Because you give background color white to child component give it to parent component.

Comment: @rish You have to set td width for that. and remove padding 9px from td.

Comment: @rish you using lots of tr and td it make confusing. suggest better to use DIV structure.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED CODE as below: I have made some css changes inline. hope that will help you.

Screenshot link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4h00ci5igdxtcf4/updatedResult.png?dl=0

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateColumns">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="templateContainer">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateColumn">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" class="leftColumnContainer"><table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top">

                                                <table style="border-right:1px solid #434343;" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="false">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td class="mcnTextContent" style="font-family: Arial,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px;" valign="top" width="164">
                                                    <span style="color:#fff;font-size: 16px;font-family: arial;">Leaky Barn Roofs</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:10px 9px 9px 1px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                                     <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/06c313ab-701e-4821-8e83-de852f0d901a.jpg" style="max-width:128px;" class="mcnImage" width="128">
                                                    </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-right: 22px; font-size: 12px;" valign="top" width="186">
                                                    <span style="color:#cccccc">Liquid Rubber MetalSafe Sealants provide corrosion protection, waterproofing and color restoration to aged rusting steel barn roofs, outlastingtypical barn roof paints for years. Our self priming coatings require only a washed surface without the removal of any rust and can be applied with a brush, roller or paint sprayer. Standard &amp; custom color top-coats are available.</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top">

                                            <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="false">
                                            <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" align="left" valign="top">
                                            <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/ec1bfef3-3b43-4356-ae66-ba8602719173.jpg" class="mcnImage" width="186">
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding:0 9px 0 9px;" valign="top" width="164">
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </tbody></table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateColumn">
                <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="centerColumnContainer"><table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                <tr>
                <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top">

                <table style="border-right:1px solid #434343;" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="false">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td class="mcnTextContent" style="font-family: Arial,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px;" valign="top" width="164">
                <span style="color:#fff;font-size: 16px;font-family: arial;">Waterproof Planter</span>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:10px 9px 9px 1px;" align="left" valign="top">
                 <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/a15958de-0729-4ccd-8228-66f5e9a80e0e.jpg" style="max-width:128px;" class="mcnImage" width="128">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-right: 17px; font-size: 12px;" valign="top" width="186">
                <span style="color:#cccccc">Simple and easy to do. Waterproof and preserve your wood planter boxes. Untreated wood planter boxes start to decay from the harmful effects of water and ultraviolet light. Two thick coats of Liquid Rubber Waterproof Sealant will provide long lasting and full protection that will secure your planter boxes for years to come.</span>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>

                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table><table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                <tr>
                <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top">


                <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="false">
                <tbody><tr>
                <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top: 7px;">
                 <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/e6686072-3933-4150-b034-eef1599bc277.jpg" class="mcnImage" width="186">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding:0 9px 0 9px;" valign="top" width="164">

                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>

                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateColumn">
                <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="rightColumnContainer"><table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                <tr>
                <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="false">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td class="mcnTextContent" style="font-family: Arial,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px;" valign="top" width="164">
                <span style="color:#fff;font-size: 16px;font-family: arial;">RV Roof Repair Boxes</span>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:10px 9px 9px 1px;" align="left" valign="top">

                <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/544220eb-ac2e-42df-bff5-7c23cbf5b70f.jpg" style="max-width:125px;" class="mcnImage" width="125">

                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="mcnTextContent" style="font-size: 12px;" valign="top" width="186">
                <span style="color:#cccccc">You may be surprised at how inexpensive and simple it can be to repair an RV, motor home or camper yourself. Using a combination of Liquid Rubber Smooth Sealant and Liquid Rubber Seam Tape, any do-it-yourself customer can seal a leaky roof, whether it's made of EPDM, TPO, fiberglass or aluminum.</span>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>


                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table><table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                <tr>
                <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="false">
                <tbody><tr>
                <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" align="left" valign="top">
                <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/dd773540-6d80-459a-b0ff-6e1002c906ba.jpg" class="mcnImage" width="186">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding:0 9px 0 9px;" valign="top" width="164">

                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>


                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try to add `code snippet` here instead of providing link to jsfiddle. It will help to simulate code on stack overflow itself.

Comment: may i know, for 3rd image?

Comment: @ rish : you can keep as it is. The change is in only first two images. I have updated my answer for your help.

Comment: @kiran: in your jsfiddle, the gap between those images still remains same. right? but i need like this http://s11.postimg.org/pzq7m2glv/Untitled_1_copy.png .thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a lot of tables for displaying a simple layout ?? Here is a table layout which you are expecting. Apply the color & other styles as you wish. This code will give you the exact result which you need. I Hope it helps.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"> Leaky Barn Roofs </th>
    <th scope="col"> Waterproof Planter </th>
    <th scope="col"> RV Roof Repair Boxes </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/06c313ab-701e-4821-8e83-de852f0d901a.jpg" alt="" width="128" align="middle" /></td>
    <td><img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/a15958de-0729-4ccd-8228-66f5e9a80e0e.jpg" width="128" /></td>
    <td><img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/544220eb-ac2e-42df-bff5-7c23cbf5b70f.jpg" width="125" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Liquid Rubber MetalSafe Sealants provide   corrosion protection, waterproofing and color restoration to aged   rusting steel barn roofs, outlastingtypical barn roof paints for years.   Our self priming coatings require only a washed surface without the   removal of any rust and can be applied with a brush, roller or paint   sprayer. Standard &amp; custom color top-coats are available.</td>
    <td>Simple and easy to do. Waterproof and   preserve your wood planter boxes. Untreated wood planter boxes start to   decay from the harmful effects of water and ultraviolet light. Two thick   coats of Liquid Rubber Waterproof Sealant will provide long lasting and   full protection that will secure your planter boxes for years to come.</td>
    <td>You may be surprised at how inexpensive and   simple it can be to repair an RV, motor home or camper yourself. Using a   combination of Liquid Rubber Smooth Sealant and Liquid Rubber Seam   Tape, any do-it-yourself customer can seal a leaky roof, whether it's   made of EPDM, TPO, fiberglass or aluminum.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/ec1bfef3-3b43-4356-ae66-ba8602719173.jpg" width="164" /></td>
    <td><img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/e6686072-3933-4150-b034-eef1599bc277.jpg" width="164" /></td>
    <td><img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/dd773540-6d80-459a-b0ff-6e1002c906ba.jpg" width="164" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't recommend using table when building layouts but since you can't change it we might as well go with it right..

So.. first thing I noticed is that you need to remove the padding on the span to correct the alignment of the title. When i say title i mean these -  (Leaky Barn Roofs ,  Waterproof Planter ,  RV Roof Repair Boxes )

```
table td span {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

or explicitly add padding 0 to each specific span if you want to..

then to align the images table in one row you need to remove them from the 3 main td's (make sure you copy them to a separate text file cause we'll be using them)

this is one of the main td i'm talking about

```
<td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%"></td>
```

when i say images table, im referring to these table, or the table that holds the images

```
<table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
```

After removing them from the main td.. you create another tr after the main tr...

the main tr is the tr that is right after this table...

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="templateContainer">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateColumn">
                //content here..
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateColumn">
                //content here..
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateColumn">
                //content here..
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
            <table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                // image here
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
            <table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                // image here
            </table>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
        <td>
            <table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                // image here
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```